# What the $@ means for xml-parsing?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I would like to access XML file

```
var_dump($xml);
```

shows

```
class SimpleXMLElement#3013 (10) {
  public $@attributes =>
   array(1) {
   'rank' =>
   string(1) "1"
   }
  public $name =>
   string(13) "name of the man"
```

I can access name of the man as

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($feed as $xml){
  $xml->name;// access here
```

However 
I have no idea how to access 'rank' in $@attributes

```
$xml->attributes->rank
```

doesnt work.

I think it is because $@attributes and $name are deferent.

I have no idea what the $@ means ...

Comment: `var_dump()` has the ability to print the entire object including private and hidden stuff you are not supposed to mess with, I guess `@attributes` is reserved by the class use only and not supposed to be accessed by the PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML is designed so that one accesses the XML nodes as if they were object properties. The `@` character is not a [valid XML node name](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wci/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.cast_iron.doc/ref_Valid_Node_Names.html), therefore, the `@` was used as the prefix for the "attributes" property (a property that holds the node's attributes). This ensures that the property would never conflict with a child node named "attributes".

To access the attribute, try one the following methods:

1. By [array index](http://www.php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5488):

   ```
   $xml['rank']
   ```
2. Via the [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

   ```
   $xml->attributes()->rank
   ```